# Почему не работает z-index для карточки товара WooCommerce?

Tags: css, woocommerce

Всем привет! Делаю магазин на WP, есть следующая задача:

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на элемент карточки подтягивалось краткое описание. Я решил задачу так:

```
.descr {
    display: none;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover .descr {
    display: inline;
}
```

Всё ок, описание подтягивается, при этом толкает нижний элемент карточки. Чтобы "толчка" не происходило, я решил наложить z-index, вот так:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #40d143;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Но беда, ничего не произошло!

Подскажите, пожалуйста: в чём дело?

З.Ы. желательно решить кейс с помощью css, потому что JSa вообще не знаю :( Это возможно?

Comment: z-index можно использовать у блоков с абсолютным и фиксированным позиционированием. У вас этот блок с классом "descr" как свёрстан?

Comment: Без позиционирования, но он и не должен накладываться на саму карточку. Он должен добавляться в карточку, тем самым расширяя блок. А блок с карточкой должен накладываться на блок с другой карточкой, вместо того, чтобы толкать его.

Comment: Не совсем корректно написал выше. У вас свойство position должно быть прописано хотя бы в relative, но оно обязано быть, иначе z-index не сработает.

Comment: На каком элементе?

Answer (score 0):

На тех элементах, которые собрались при помощи z-index выстраивать, нужно всем указать `position`. Вот только есть мнение, что это не поможет, если ваши блоки расположены не выше и ниже, а слева и справа относительно друг друга.

Когда какому-то блоку прописываете `display: none;`, то его ширина становится 0 пикселов, а когда снова прописываете `display: inline;` то он обретает свою ширину и толкает другие блоки. Чтобы решить именно эту проблему, лучше такому блоку прописать прозрачность: `opacity: 0;`, а при наведении мышки смените на единицу. Так блок будет невидимым, но габариты свои не потеряет. Соседние блоки будут его габариты учитывать.

Comment: Это хорошая идея, я возьму её в запас, потому что хочется всё же выполнить этот вариант. Смотрите, я хочу сделать как на этом сайте: https://rus-buket.ru/ . Блок при наведение накладывается на нижний